# google apps script soap client without wsdl

Tags: soap, google-apps-script

I am attempting to access the Numara Footprints web services API from google apps script.  There is no wsdl for the web service, but the methods are well documented.  All of the examples of using Google Apps Script Soap Service assume the existence of a wsdl file, which makes it a non-starter for my purposes.  So I am trying to use UrlFetchApp instead.  By using the sample php code that Numara Footprints provides, I established what the request should look like, and wrote the following code in google apps script:

```
function sendHttpPost() {
var payload= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope'+
'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"'+
'xmlns:ns1="MRWebServices"'+
'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"' +
  'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
    'xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"' +
      'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">'+
        '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
        '<ns1:MRWebServices__search>'+
        '<param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">ACCOUNT NAME</param0>'+
        '<param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</param1>'+
         '<param2 xsi:type="xsd:string"></param2>'+
          '<param3 xsi:type="xsd:string">'+
"SELECT * from MASTER1 where mrid='16888'</param3>"+
           '</ns1:MRWebServices__search>'+
            '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';



var headers =
  {
   "SOAPAction" :encodeURIComponent("MRWebServices#MRWebServices__search")
           };

var options =
{
  "contentType": "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
  "method" : "post",
  "headers" : headers,  
  "payload" : payload
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://FOOTPRINTS SERVER/MRcgi/MRWebServices.pl", options);
}
```

This code contacts the server successfully and gets the following error message returned:

```
Request failed for http://FOOTPRINTS SERVER/MRcgi/MRWebServices.pl 
returned code 500. Server response: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Application failed during request deserialization: 
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 70, byte 70 at 
C:/FootPrints/bin/Perl/lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187 </faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope> (line 40)
```

I don't know of any way to get more detailed error messages, and I don't know what the problem is.  The xml that I am sending is copied directly from the PHP code that works perfectly.

I'm wondering if anyone either:

1. can see a problem with the google apps script code above or
2. can tell me how to use the Google Apps Script soap service when I don't have a wsdl file or
3. knows of a way to get a web service to return more error details.

Thanks in advance.  I've looked everywhere that I can think of but not found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The payload var in the above code needed spaces between the XML elements. Corrected code (note spaces at the end of each line):

```
var payload= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ' +
'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope '+
'xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '+
'xmlns:ns1="MRWebServices" '+
'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
  'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" ' +
      'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> '+
        '<SOAP-ENV:Body> '+
        '<ns1:MRWebServices__search> '+
        '<param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">ACCOUNT NAME</param0> '+
        '<param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</param1> '+
         '<param2 xsi:type="xsd:string"></param2> '+
          '<param3 xsi:type="xsd:string"> '+
           "SELECT * from MASTER22 where mrid='16888'</param3> "+
           '</ns1:MRWebServices__search> '+
            '</SOAP-ENV:Body> '+
            '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
```

Also, in the headers, I did not need to use encodeURIComponent().  Corrected code:

```
var headers =
  {
   "SOAPAction" :"MRWebServices#MRWebServices__search"
           };
```